# Deploy Jersey Application on OpenShift

Tags: java, spring, jersey, tomcat7, openshift

I'm trying to provide a Jersey Application on OpenShift using Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0). The deployment is successful, but my application is not started.
Analyzing the log application not found any errors, but I saw that my WebApplicationContext is closed before the Spring inject my services and DAO's.

- **[MyApplication.log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hxZfGZYBzOaz06iWoxI25aATxzrxWdDk1X4R5Nz_Iyg/edit?usp=sharing)** - In it I highlighted the two final
  lines, where the contexts of application and persistence are
  closed... **What can be causing this?**

IMPORTANT INFORMATIONS:

- I'm using Postgres 9.2 cartridge in my OpenShift application;
- My application is on GitHub. Here are some links to relevant files in the context of this question: **[persistence.xml](https://github.com/falvojr/msplearning/blob/master/rest-app/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml)** and **[web.xml](https://github.com/falvojr/msplearning/blob/master/rest-app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml)**;
- I'm providing deploys using the OpenShift RHC Client Tools.